# text alignment between Farsi and English in Tex studio (Using XEpersian)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, texstudio, xepersian

My problem is related to my editor ( Tex studio).

I am going to use XEpersian and write Farsi in Tex studio but there is a problem!

when I write English between Farsi text, the alignment between Farsi and English get wrong.

This problem is very annoying.

How can I fix it?

```
برای مقایسه این سه روش از معیار فاصله دوماتریس  $ ||P-A||_2$
استفاده می کنیم.
```

As you can see  '$ ||P-A||_2$' is not in the right place.

I would appreciate for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this has nothing to do with `xepersian` but it is the editor issue. All available editors have the same issue. The best solution is to to type your math formula in a separate line.

```
برای مقایسه این سه روش از معیار فاصله دوماتریس  
$||P-A||_2$
استفاده می کنیم.
```